# Mvc Invalid operation exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to retrieve employees from my-sql server database depending on the id parameter passed.  For example: `http://localhost:66666/employee/details/1 <---the parameter`
and match the parameter with an id in the database and display it in the view.  For some reason I am getting an invalid operation exception on this line in the employee controller: `Employee employee = EmployeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);`

I am not sure if the error actually originates there.

employee controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCTutorials.Models;

namespace MVCTutorials.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Details(int id)//id =paramenter 
        {

            EmployeeContext EmployeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

            Employee employee = EmployeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
            return View(employee);

        }
    }
}
```

employee model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCTutorials.Models
{
    [Table("TblEmp")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

employee view

```
@model MVCTutorials.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employeee Details";
}

<h2>Employeee Details</h2>

<table style="font-family:Arial;">
    <tr><!--The Row-->
        <td>
                <b>Employee Id: </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.EmployeeID
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td>@Model.Gender</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td>@Model.City </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Employee context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCTutorials.Models
{
    public  class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Global.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MVCTutorials
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        //Happens when appplication first starts
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //Purpose used to initalize your database e.g if you dont have a database created already this will create one for you(database,tables and data will all be created)
            // we pass null saying we dont want any of this
            Database.SetInitializer<MVCTutorials.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting exactly? Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Single method Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.
so you can use SingleOrDefault function which return null if you havnt any desired row.

```
Employee employee = EmployeeContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN for Enumerable.Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx):

> InvalidOperationException 
>   The input sequence contains more than one element.
>   -or-
>   The input sequence is empty.

I believe you have either more than one Employee or none who matches the criteria so exception is thrown.

You should either use `First()` if it is possible that more than one `Employee` exists or use `SingleOrDefault` and check for `null`.

Comment: sorry can you give me an example of how i would test for this that i could use break points and step into it to see if you are correct,im not brilliant at writing debugging tests.

Comment: Why you would want to debug a test? Simply change `Single` to `First` or `SingleOrDefault` - it all depends on what you are trying to achieve and what are the requirements of you functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Single` method, use `Find` and then verify if it was found.

```
Employee employee = EmployeeContext.Employees.Find(id);
if (employee == null)
    // not found on database
```

As [per documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx), `Single` method will success only if there is exaclty one record matching your criteria. Not more not less than one record.